# Is it possible to send a string from a local html file to NSUserDefaults in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, xcode

For example, if I have an HTML page with a web login, can I then store that information in the NSUserDefaults?

Any examples or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the page loaded in a UIWebView the only way you can access content inside it is to use

```
-(NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

To run some javascript that would output something as a string, which you could capture and store in NSUserDefaults like any other string.  Without knowing exactly what info you need in that web view, it's hard to be more specific.